# Convergent to $0$ in norm, but not convergent continuous function sequence

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

The problem is :

> Give an example of a sequence of continuous functions such that the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does not converge at any point but $||f_n||_p \rightarrow 0$ ($1 \le p < \infty$).

I could make an example (but, not a sequence of "continuous" functions) using some characteristic functions made by some intervals ${I_n} = {[0,1],[0,1/2],[1/2,1],[0,1/4],[1/4,2/4], ....}$ .

But, how can I make a sequence of "continuous" functions? Could you give me a great example, please?

Comment: You can just modify the characteristic functions to be continuous, a simple smoothing at the boundary

Comment: Do you really mean to write $[1/2,2/4] =\{1/2\}$ in that sequence of intervals?

Comment: Oh, now I editted, 1/2 to 1/4.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you suggest, I understand that you are looking for functions defined on $[0,1]$. Let me help you by abstracting your construction a little bit.

First, you start with some base function, say $\chi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\chi(x) = 1$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $\chi(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-\infty,-2]\cup[2,+\infty)$, and anything for $x \in (-2,-1) \cup (1,2)$. In your case, you started with $\chi = 0$ on these junction parts, but you could also make affine junctions so that $\chi \in C^0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$, or even smoother junctions so that $\chi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$.

Now you let
$$
f_n(x) := \chi \left( \frac{x - x_n}{\delta_n} \right),
$$
where $\delta_n > 0$ is a sequence of numbers to be chosen, and $x_n \in [0,1]$ also.

To guarantee that $\|f_n\|_{L^p(0,1)} \to 0$, it is sufficient (and necessary) that $\delta_n \to 0$ (the width of the functions decreases).

To guarantee that, for every $x^* \in [0,1]$, $f_n(x^*)$ does not have a limit, you need to make sure that the sequence "visits" every part of $[0,1]$ an infinite number of times.

You can workout the nifty computations and give explicit formulas for $\delta_n$ and $x_n$, or you could define an algorithmic "sweeping" sequence defined by recursion. For example, set $(\delta_0, x_0) := (1,0)$ and
$$
(\delta_{n+1},x_{n+1}) := \begin{cases}
(\delta_n, x_n + \delta_n) & \text{if } x_n < 1, \\
(\delta_n / 2, 0) & \text{if } x_n \geq 1.
\end{cases}
$$
With such a program, you can check that, for every $x^* \in [0,1]$ and every $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $n_0,n_1 \geq N$ such that $f_{n_0}(x^*) = 0$ and $f_{n_1}(x^*) = 1$, preventing that the sequence $f_n(x^*)$ has a limit.